# How to shorten this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you create an automatic method for the function below? The only thing what changes is the .eq() part. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
$(".gomb").eq(0).click(function(){              
      $('.popup-overlay').eq(0).slideDown();
});

$(".gomb").eq(1).click(function(){              
      $('.popup-overlay').eq(1).slideDown();
});

$(".gomb").eq(2).click(function(){              
      $('.popup-overlay').eq(2).slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".gomb").click(function(){              
      $('.popup-overlay').eq($(this).index(".gomb")).slideDown();
});
```

or

```
var $gombs = $(".gomb").click(function(){              
      $('.popup-overlay').eq($gombs.index(this)).slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
$(".gomb").click(function(){              
      $('.popup-overlay').eq($(this).index()).slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$(".gomb:eq(0) , .gomb:eq(1) , .gomb:eq(2)").click(function(){              
  $('.popup-overlay').eq($(this).index()).slideDown();
});
```

This is for the indexes `0,1,2`.If you want for all the indexes then use like

```
$(".gomb").click(function(){              
  $('.popup-overlay').eq($(this).index()).slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
$(".gomb").click(function(e){              
      e.target.slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for u,

```
$(".gomb").click(function(){              
  $(this).slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that will do it exactly the same as your code, making only the first three ".gomb" elements trigger a slideDown of the popup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
        $(".gomb").eq(ii).click(function(){              
              $('.popup-overlay').eq(ii).slideDown();
        });
    }
});
```